# Crystal Report and ODP.Net

Tags: c#, oracle, crystal-reports

We are using CR XI on Oralce. We applying RLS (Row Level Security) in DB. RLS will base on information we set in the session (by calling  trans_pkg.set_username('abc')) to decide which data rows can appear in dataset. But CR seems to have its own Connection to Oracle. We have no way to run a package like: trans_pkg.set_username('abc') before CR query data.
It is now the big security risk to our system.
If you have any solution please help me.

Comment: What about calling `trans_pkg.set_username('abc')` within the Oracle stored procedure used to power the Crystal Report?

Comment: Do You mean add a command in CR like select trans_pkg.set_username('abc') from dual? If we have many queries in CR, each queries will use the same Oracle session or create on its own?

Comment: Hi OMG Ponies, your solution is right if the query select trans_pkg.set_username('abc') from dual run first in all queries. But how to make sure that this query always run first?

Comment: I think you can make it run first by creating a subreport in the report header.  You probably don't want it to display anything, but you can't suppress it, so use overlay.  (It's been a year since I've used Crystal Reports, I'm not sure if this exactly solution will work but I know I've used something similar before.)  Another way to do it is to use a pipelined function as the table, and call the package before you select and pipe rows.  That sounds complicated, but doing it all in Oracle is usually much better than doing weird CR formatting.

Comment: hi jonearles, Can you show me links related to your second solution? In your first solution, we tried it but the problem is how to make sure that this query is the first to run when load CR?

Comment: Here's an example of a pipelined function: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#sthref2351    Also, there are a couple of ways to tell exactly what part of a report runs first: create an autonomous transaction function that writes to another table when it's called and include that function in each query, or use a custom UFL to write to a file.  Although both of those methods are probably more complicated than using a pipelined function.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used crystal against oracle, only sql server, but the answer should be the same. When you set thwe connection info for the report, you need to specify the user name and password. The database should use this info to identify the user and assign correct access permissions.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Our system is 3 tiers, user Database is the same for all sessions. The only way is executing some procedure before querying data. Any suggestion?

Comment: do you mean execute a 'stored procedure' in the db, or a procedure in you data access tier, or what? in any case, what does the procedure do?

Comment: execute stored procedure. we have a package trans_pkg. In this package, we have a global variable g_username. trans_pkg.set_username(p_username varchar2) simply set  g_username:= p_username; and in RLS context we filter only rows that this username can access.

Comment: I would guess that your report is using a different connection to Oracle than your stored proc call, and it therefore doesn't see your g_username variable. It sounds like you will need to use the Crystal API to set the user name in the report before it gets run. Look at Table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo. You use it to set the db name, user name, and password. Again, this works for sql server - my Oracle experience is limited and way in the past, so it may not work exactly the same way.

Comment: How are you using CR. Are the reports in a Business Object Server or are you using a crystal reports viewer

Comment: Just Viewer. Our Report Server is a replacement of BO Server.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the crystal report viewer instead of a BO Server you can just use DataSets as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164621/using-crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2005-c-net-windows-app/278916#278916)

If you were using a BO Server you'd need to create another procedure that first calls sets the user name and then execute the report source procedure or the query.

Comment: In our system, user can create new rpt files and upload to report server and others can view those reports. In a rpt file, there is a various of queries. I think we can use that approach in this case.

Comment: :) sorry, I am new to this forum. I will find the way to do it :)